# Prove significant effect of third variable on a correlation

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, confounding, stratification

So I was measuring correlations in Boxscores of basketball players in the NBA.

```
3PA  DRB            -0.205499
```

I was trying to find some interesting correlations. This is a correlation between 3 point shots attempted (3PA) and defensive rebounds (DRB). It is something that is not correlated with the development of play. Players who take more 3 point shots are usually guards that rebound less. So I tried to account for this by stratifying. I divided the data into two groups (centers/forwards & guards).

```
0.09863996993231319 -0.15288533987772265
```

These are the correlations between the two attributes for the groups. The correlations are smaller, but is it significant?

What I want to know is how can you statistically prove this type of effect?

Comment: Searching on "statistical significance correlation" should give you everything you need to know.  Also, did you notice the minus sign on your first result?

Comment: Of course I noticed the minus, it is a negative correlation.

Comment: I knew about statistical significance of the correlation before. But I was asking something else. Well I suppose I could test all the correlations and see if they are no longer significant after the introduction of the third variable.

Comment: Regression interaction will test the difference between two groups' correlations.   But to test whether a change after introducing another variable will be statistically significant -- I don't see how any distribution under the null hypothesis would be known.  Thus I don't see how one could perform such a test.

Comment: I need to learn about Regression more.